# Cascade persistence with HashMap

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My parent class:

```
@Entity
public class FooParent 
{
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true,mappedBy="parent")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    public Map<FooChild,FooChild> kids = new HashMap<>();

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    Integer id;

    public FooParent ()
    {
    }
}
```

and child class:

```
@Entity
public class FooChild 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    FooParent parent;

    public FooChild (FooParent parent)
    {
        this.parent=parent;
    }
}
```

I'm finding that cascaded persistence only seems to apply to the *value* of a Map, not the *key*.  If I do this:

```
FooParent foo = new FooParent();
FooChild kid1 = new FooChild(foo);
FooChild kid2 = new FooChild(foo);
foo.kids.put(kid1,kid2);
hibSession.persist(foo);
```

I get:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.cards.FooChild
```

If I persist() `kid1` before `foo`, then all works fine.  Also, if I change `kids` to `Map<Integer,FooChild>`, it works, as does List

Is this a limitation, or is the something else I need to do in order to cascade persistence of a mapped Map key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391498/mapping-a-java-util-mapentity-entity-in-hibernate-using-jpa-annotations sounds similar.

Comment: Yep, same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a java.util.map<entity, entity> in hibernate using JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391498/mapping-a-java-util-mapentity-entity-in-hibernate-using-jpa-annotations)